# GooglePlaces autocomplete - more than one input

Tags: google-app-engine, google-places-api

I'm using autocomplete API Google. I want to have 3 inputs:

- Country
- City
- Province

Is there any possibility to implement this 3 inputs on the same page with autocomplete for each? with one, everything works perfectly. But with more than one, code doesn't work properly (without any errors). Is there any restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, use one input (who can input data into 3 inputs at the same time, anyway?), and when you get the full autocompleted result, split the result into separate (uneditable) fields.

Comment: but i want to put 3 inputs, one below the other, where user will have autocomplete: firstly country, secondly province, thirdly city. I send to database separately City/Country/Province, so I have to get all of this information. I know that I can get this infos from geolocation, but still i want to have 3 inputs (if this option is possible).

Comment: please, open http://maps.google.com/ then enter "2345" into the address box. you immediately will see the list of possible addresses for that particular number. don't need to type the whole thing. that's how autocompletion is supposed to work. and when it has finished and you've got the resulting address, you may split it down and save as you like. trying to do this with 3 inputs is counter-intuitive and counterproductive at the same time.

Comment: thanks for reply. Is there any possibility to force this one autocomplete input in this format? for example -Virginia Beach, Wirginia 23455, United Stanes (city, state, country)

Comment: here's an explanation how it should work: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.jp/2012/05/faster-address-entry-with-google-places.html and here are example requests and responses: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete -- autocomplete returns not the single item, but several possible matches based on your request and order matches based on their perceived relevance. then you may show these matches to your user and let him/her to select the right one.